# ColdFusion ajax post request not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am trying to create a ajax request in ColdFusion, but I am getting parser error.

My request:

```
var data=[];
        data.push({'id':10});
        data.push({'notes':'Test'});

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "post",
            url: "components/activity.cfc",
            data: {
                    method:"ajaxUpdateNotes",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data)
                },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( objResponse ){
                console.debug('OK');
            },
            error: function( objRequest, strError ){
                console.debug(strError);
            }
        });
```

I have my CFC actitivy file only with a dump (for testing).

```
component displayName="Activity" {
    remote any function ajaxUpdateNotes(data) returnformat="JSON"{
        data = deserializeJSON(arguments.data);
        WriteDump(data); abort;

        result = 0;
        return serializeJSON(result);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: In your method you have, WriteDump(data); abort; , so you're not returning anything, don't expect your ajax success to work.

Comment: .. and while that is probably the issue, phrases like "getting parsererror." are ambiguous. If you are getting an error, always include the actual error message in the question.

Comment: I do not want to return data. I just want to send data in order to update my table in database

Answer (score 0):

1.when pushing paired values, the key does not need quote:

```
data.push({id:10});
data.push({notes:'Test'});
```

2. "abort" stops your target page from producing result.

Comment: The problem is that I want to DUMP the arguments to check if they are correct

Comment: Ok. Why do you abort after Dump? and why do you return 0?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get the `'parsererror'`, remove `WriteDump(data); abort;`

To check if the arguments are correct, while testing, return the arguments from your method, inspect in the browser's console.

```
component displayName="Activity" {
    remote any function ajaxUpdateNotes(data) returnformat="JSON"{
        data = deserializeJSON(arguments.data);
        return serializeJSON(data);
    }
}
```

After you update your table, return true at least `return serializeJSON('true');` If the update fails return 'false' and deal with it on the front end.

Comment: Thank you, but now I have a problem that if I call my ajax one time, it works (does the update), but if I call inside a loop, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try on Success 200 of the $Ajax call like below.

First JSON.Stringify followed by JSON.parse.

```
success: function(data) {                                                                                                
    var objectSuccessData = JSON.stringify(data); 
    var objectSuccessParsedData = JSON.parse(objectSuccessData ); 
}
```